# 404 after installing package with npm

Tags: angular, npm, angular2-forms

I'm trying to build an angular2 application in ASP core with Visual Studio 2015.
Following [this tutorial](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html) I want to set up a simple form to search a database for whatever the user has entered.
At first, Visual Studio told me it cannot find @angular/forms when trying to import FormGroup into my module:

```
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
```

So I included @angular/forms in my package.json and as that didn't change a thing, I installed it manually (including dependencies in the packages.json and running `npm install`). Now VS can find the module but when I try to run the app the browser returns this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:23301/@angular/forms
```

Where does it actually get that url from? Why does it work with all the other packages I've included (like `angular2/core` or `angular2/http` but not with this one? Why does this module look so strange anyway and not like the other angular2 modules? Why can I actually find FormBuilder and Validators in `angular2/common`? Is this `@angular/forms` deprecated and I actually need to get the FormGroup elsewhere? If so, where is it included?

Comment: The modules no longer have names with `angular2` in them. `@angular/forms` should be used with `@angular/core`, etc. It sounds like you have a mishmash of versions.

Comment: I did try to look for which version is currently the latest one and which versions of other packages it depends on but I was not able to find anything.